# Streaming a big file directly to the database

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I'm using a [WCF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Communication_Foundation) application to save a file received via streaming to the database.
I interact with my database using [LINQ to SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query#LINQ_to_SQL). I need a way to insert any data I receive automatically to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linq-to-SQL isn't the best choice when inserted large items into a database table. It's well suited for "normal" records like addresses and so on - but large files, you're probably better off storing those into the database directly using straight ADO.NET.

What *version* of SQL Server are you using in the background? If you're on SQL Server 2008, and if your files are often or even typically larger than 1 MB in size, you might want to investigate the FILESTREAM feature. This would allow you to stream the data into a `SqlFileStream` object.

Otherwise, Woot4Moo's idea of a stored proc to handle the storing into a BLOB column should work just fine (or an inline SQL query, if you and your DBA are OK with that).

Answer (score 2):

Call a stored procedure that does an insert.  If that isn't what you are looking for be more specific in the question.